# Refreshing lower environments with prod copy

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I know this isn't something new and people might be doing this in their environment. I have a requirement to do refreshes monthly, weekly etc in lower environments and I wanted to know if there is a quicker approach to this. I know we can do a backup and restore etc through SQL job (I would love to know if there is an automated script which takes care of the entire process). Also, instead of doing a full database restore every month is there a way we can only send changes that happened during the month or the week that way it would save a lot of time and wastage of space. I am not sure on how to achieve the second option of shipping only the changes. We aren't considering any HA technologies for x reasons so please do not give me those options. Any script that you have that can achieve this or if you are doing something similar in your environment and have the necessary details and scripts then please do share the same. Is there any tool that can achieve this but obviously this won't be my first option unless we can't do it via writing t-sql code. Also, our boxes are VMs so is there a possibility we can leverage the features and capabilities by taking file snapshots and delivering it to the lower environments (sorry I am a bit naive on VM capabilities and techniques) rather than doing backup and restore natively through SQL.

Fyi...we want complete data not just bare schema. Also, please do not share solutions using SSIS.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you perform the recovery portion of a database restore, it loses the ability to restore additional backups from the source database. Depending on your setup, you *may* be able to get away with shipping only an additional differential backup from the source system. But you'd still need to restore the full backup again.